# Convert IST date to UTC in RSS feed

Tags: javascript, date, rss

I've a Date in string format 'Wed, 08 Apr 2020 15:24:06 IST'
I want to convert it into javascript Date so that I can perform operations.
I want to get UTC date from IST or whatever is passed by the api and I have to convert it as per user timezone so I can't remove IST from it. IST(Indian Standard Time) is just an example it could be AET(Australian Eastern Time),EET(Eastern European Time), etc...

```js
new Date('Wed, 08 Apr 2020 15:24:06 IST')
```

I'm Getting Invalid Date

This string comes from the [Times Of India RSS feeds](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rss.cms), such as [this one](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/-2128672765.cms).  How do I handle time zone abbreviations in RSS feeds?

Comment: You've tagged `Luxon` and `MomentJS` but I can't see any related code!

Comment: actually I want to get UTC date from IST or whatever is passed by the api and I have to convert it as per user timezone so I can't remove IST from it. IST(Indian Standard Time) is just an example it could be AET(Australian Eastern Time),EET(Eastern European Time), etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without additional context, this isn't possible.  Time zone abbreviations are not standardized nor are they unique.

In your example, you said `IST` means "Indian Standard Time" to you, however `IST` is *also* used for "Israel Standard Time" and "Irish Standard Time".  All of which have very different time zone offsets.

Another common example is `CST`, which could be "Central Standard Time", "Cuba Standard Time", or "China Standard Time".

Instead - you should go back to the original source and obtain a time zone offset (such as `+05:30`) or a time zone identifier (such as `Asia/Kolkata`), or derive that context in some other way.

You said you were retrieving this timestamp from [an RSS feed from Times of India](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/-2128672765.cms).  That is the type of additional context I'm speaking of.  Since you know that it's and Indian news source, you can safely assume that `IST` means India Standard Time.

You should know that the format of the RSS feed at Times of India is not using timestamps correctly.  The [RSS 2.0 specification](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html) requires timestamps to be in [RFC 822 format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5).  In that format, `IST` is not a valid time zone.  Indeed, if you put it into a site like [Feed Validator](https://www.feedvalidator.org/), it will give you the error ["element must be an RFC-822 date-time"](https://www.feedvalidator.org/docs/error/InvalidRFC2822Date.html).

Note that [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5) is old and outdated. It's been superseded with [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3), and then again by [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.3).  Time zone abbreviations have all been obsoleted and moved to the [`obs-zone`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-4.3) section.  Thus, they really shouldn't be used at all.  Only numeric offsets should appear.  That said, *many* RSS implementations follow the old standard, and thus it is reasonable to accept some of the abbreviations specified in `obs-zone`.  Specifically, all implementations should accept the following:

```
"Z"    == "+0000"
"UT"   == "+0000"
"GMT"  == "+0000"
"EST"  == "-0500"
"EDT"  == "-0400"
"CST"  == "-0600"
"CDT"  == "-0500"
"MST"  == "-0700"
"MDT"  == "-0600"
"PST"  == "-0800"
"PDT"  == "-0700"
```

(The other military zones "A" - "Y" should never be used.)

Note that `IST` is not among them.  Thus to answer your question directly, when parsing an RFC 822 timestamp that contains a non-standard time zone abbreviation, you will need to replace the abbreviation with an offset yourself before parsing.  In this case:

```
var s = 'Wed, 08 Apr 2020 15:24:06 IST';
var d = new Date(s.replace('IST', '+0530'));
```

You could also replace the other `obs-zone` abbreviations I listed, but it should generally not be necessary.  Most implementations of ECMAScript will parse those (even though they are not required to by spec).

If you encounter other RSS feeds with other time zone abbreviations, you will need to manually make a determination as to how to interpret them.  There is no definitive list.

Some additional reading:

- [RSS Best Practices for dates and times](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#data-types-datetime)
- [The RSS 2.0 Specification](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html)
- [The ATOM specification](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/atom.html), which moves away from RFC 822 and uses [RFC 3339 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) (which are [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant) instead, in part to specifically avoid this problem.

Comment: After a few research I came to know that IST is not only India Standard Time. I can't even able to produce date like that but some how I'm getting this type of date in Times Of India RSS feed. https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/-2128672765.cms you can have a look on this. In this example I can simply replace IST with +0330 of GMT+330 that will solve this issue but it might happen that another country RSS feed may use date as per IST like format then I have to face same issue so I'm looking for a functionality that gives me UTC date as per date given in that format.

Comment: `+0530`, not `+0330`.  But yes.  See my updated, expanded answer.  I'll also edit your question to frame it for RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
moment('Wed, 08 Apr 2020 15:24:06').utc();
```

And you are getting error because of IST just remove that and it will not give you an error

If you want only date then use this:

```
moment('Wed, 08 Apr 2020 15:24:06').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: actually I want to get UTC date from IST or whatever is passed by the api and I have to convert it as per user timezone so I can't remove IST from it. IST(Indian Standard Time) is just an example it could be AET(Australian Eastern Time),EET(Eastern European Time), etc...

Comment: You are doing wrong, correct format is `new Date('Wed, 08 Apr 2020 15:24:06 (India Standard Time)'` not `new Date('Wed, 08 Apr 2020 15:24:06 IST')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use moment.utc()

```js
var res = moment.utc("Wed, 08 Apr 2020 15:24:06",'DD-MMM-YYYY').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: actually I want to get UTC date from IST or whatever is passed by the api and I have to convert it as per user timezone so I can't remove IST from it. IST(Indian Standard Time) is just an example it could be AET(Australian Eastern Time),EET(Eastern European Time), etc...